# TinyMCE formatted text in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, formatting, tinymce

I have been searching for an answer for this for quite some time now, and I haven't been able to find a logical one yet.

I want to use TinyMCE to allow users to post formatted blogs. I don't want to force the user to use HTML tags in the textarea to put a new paragraph, they should just be able to hit the return key to get a new line, push a button to get bolded text, etc... My question is, if I am storing these blog posts in a mysql database, how can I preserve the formatting in the database securely and then show the blog post from the database with the formatting intact?

Comment: Save HTML, read HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getContent`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent):

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

it will return you the HTML of current tinymce editor, and you can send it to your server.

Comment: So store the raw TinyMCE HTML into the database then just echo it out?