# TinyMCE results in php

Tags: php

I am trying to use the TinyMCE editor in the admin section of my site. I would like for it to echo in the php but I have no clue how to do that. I have searched the site but I couldnt find how to make the TinyMCE raw code get stored in the database then echo on my site.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961732/tinymce-formatted-text-in-mysql-database) here but dont understand what code I would put for it to get the results in php.

Here is my php code that grabs the desc text from the database

```
<div><p><?php echo wordwrap($desc, 3000, "<br />");?></p>
```

Then I have this in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea"
});
</script>
```

And this is what I have for the editor in the backend

```
<textarea name="desc" rows="10" cols="55" wrap="physical" type="text" id="about-textarea"></textarea>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize TinyMCE with the selector "textare". This means TinyMCE will look for any textarea on your page and replace it by an editor. Your code does not contain any textarea and so there is no editor inserted.

Yout might try to do it like this

```
<textarea name="mycontent"><?php echo wordwrap($desc, 3000, "<br />");?></textarea>
```

The HTML code generated by the editor will be written to the textarea and will be send to your php script when the form is submitted like any other input box.

Comment: When I add the "<textarea>" it is adding a small box around the content on the product page... I added the TinyMCE box to my admin side, I am trying to get that to echo on the frontend product page. I apologize if I didnt explain it well enough

Comment: In the backend (when editing the text) you need the textarea. In the frontend (when showing it to the user) you do not need it. Just use the same paragraph tag as before.

Comment: I edited my initial question with the code being used in the backend

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea.my_tiny"
});
</script>
```

Set class or id of your tinymce editor

```
<textarea class="my_tiny"></textarea>
```

then on below this

```
<script>
tinyMCE.get('my_tiny').setContent(<?php echo $desc; ?>);
</script>
```